# Getting MsBuild to build all the solutions in sub folders

Tags: msbuild

I've got a directory that contains multiple VS solutions. There are solutions added on a regular basis and I would prefer not to maintain a solution that contains all the other solutions. Is there a way to get msbuild to find all the solution files in the subfolders of a given folder and build each solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't played with msbuild for a while, so I don't know if it can do it by itself, but you could try something hacky with some batch files.
Like so:

```
FOR /D %%i IN (*.*) DO CALL makedir.bat %%i
```

Where makedir.bat calls msbuild for the solution in the directory.